# Webapp and notification

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-applications, notifications

Which is the best way to notify a webapp (need to work in chrome and safari) from server? (my webapp is in angular for information).
Is it possible to receive UDP broacast with a webapp? (If not, that will not be a problem i can do a little app that will receive the broadcast and translate it to a notification but which is the best one for webapp that the question...)

This probably a double post but i didn't find a real example so if you can give me an example of what i need to do that gona be great :).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what you want, but if you need to notify your webapp from server in real time you probably will be interested by websocket technology. You can get information about this subject here: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/WebSockets

If you use a nodeJs server, socket.io seems to be great and there are good exemples and documentation in the official website (http://socket.io/).